# pandas: draw stacked bar graph with year and values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a df like:

```
name  year  total packets
pak   2016  4
pak   2018  18
pak   2022  5
ind   2019  10
ind   2021  9
afg   2017  2
afg   2018  32
afg   2022  31
```

I need to draw a stacked-bar graph that shows each name on x-axis and the year on y-axis with total packets labeled within the stack bar for each name. Something like the answer here: [Python: Stacked bar plot based on values from multiple columns within the same DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724325/python-stacked-bar-plot-based-on-values-from-multiple-columns-within-the-same-d)

I tried something like:

```
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

        # group by each column counting the size of each category values
        for col in old_df:
            grped = old_df.groupby(col).size()
            grped = grped.rename(grped.index.name)
            temp_df = temp_df.merge(grped.to_frame(), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

        # plot the merged dataframe
        temp_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Do you try pivoting and not working for you?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index="name", columns='year', values='packets', aggfunc='sum').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Comment: @jezrael this gives the sum on the y-axis, I need the year on y-axis and the sum of packects labeled in side the bar chunk for each year